# How does daemon thread work in Producer Consumer? Unable to get it working

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

I have implemented Producer Consumer code, but what I want to know is how the daemon thread works?

In the following code Producer and Consumer are working fine. 
As per my knowledge Daemon thread is a service provider for other threads. Daemon thread waits for the other threads to die, so how should I use it in my program or application.

In the following code I have set Producer as a daemon thread but I don't see any diffrence.

Producer thread dies and does not waits for the Consumer to die.

How is this working?

```
package com.test;

import com.custome.util.CustomeLinkedListImpl;

class Produce implements Runnable {
    private CustomeLinkedListImpl linkedList;

    public Produce(CustomeLinkedListImpl linkedList) {
        super();
        this.linkedList = linkedList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
            produce(i);
        }

    }

    public void produce(int i) {

        synchronized (linkedList) {
            while (linkedList.size() == 10) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Producer thread "
                            + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + " wait for Consumer: " + linkedList.size());
                    linkedList.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        synchronized (linkedList) {
            System.out.println("Producer thread "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " produce: " + i);
            linkedList.addFirst(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) Math.random() * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            linkedList.notify();

        }

    }
}

class Consume implements Runnable {
    private CustomeLinkedListImpl linkedList;

    public Consume(CustomeLinkedListImpl linkedList) {
        super();
        this.linkedList = linkedList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true)
            consume();
    }

    public void consume() {
        synchronized (linkedList) {
            while (linkedList.size() == 0) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Consumer Thread "
                            + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + " waiting for consumer : size=0");
                    linkedList.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }

            synchronized (linkedList) {
                System.out.println("Consumer thread "
                        + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " consume: "
                        + linkedList.remove().getData());

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                linkedList.notify();
            }
        }
    }

}

public class ThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CustomeLinkedListImpl linkedListImpl = new CustomeLinkedListImpl();

        Produce producer = new Produce(linkedListImpl);
        Consume consumer = new Consume(linkedListImpl);

        Thread prodThread = new Thread(producer, "StackOverFlow");
        Thread consThread = new Thread(consumer, "Users");
        prodThread.setDaemon(true);
        prodThread.start();
        consThread.start();

    }

}
```

.

```
package com.custome.util;



public class CustomeLinkedListImpl {

    LinkedNode first;

    public CustomeLinkedListImpl() {
        first = null;
    }

    public void addNode(int data) {
        LinkedNode currentNode = new LinkedNode(data, null);

        if (first == null) {
            first = currentNode;
            return;
        }

        LinkedNode tmpNode = null;
        for (tmpNode = first; tmpNode.next != null; tmpNode = tmpNode.next) {

        }
        tmpNode.next = currentNode;
    }

    public void addFirst(int data) {
        LinkedNode currentNode = new LinkedNode(data, null);

        currentNode.next = first;
        first = currentNode;
    }

    public void insertAtPosition(int data, int position) {
        int i = 0;
        LinkedNode currentNode = new LinkedNode(data, null);
        if (position == 0) {
            addFirst(data);
            return;
        }
        LinkedNode tmpNode = first;
        while (tmpNode.next != null) {
            i++;
            if (i == position) {
                currentNode.next = tmpNode.next;
                tmpNode.next = currentNode;
            } else
                tmpNode = tmpNode.next;

        }

    }

    public LinkedNode remove() {
        LinkedNode removedNode = null;
        if (first == null) {
            System.out.println("Null Pointer Exception");

        } else {
            LinkedNode tmpNode = first;
            first = first.next;
            removedNode = tmpNode;

        }
        return removedNode;
    }

    public LinkedNode remove(int position) {
        LinkedNode removedNode = null;
        if (first == null) {
            System.out.println("Null Pointer Exception");

        } else {
            if (position == 0) {
                first = first.next;
            } else {
                LinkedNode tmpNode = first;
                int i = 0;
                while (tmpNode != null) {

                    i++;
                    if (i == position) {
                        removedNode = tmpNode.next;
                        tmpNode.next = tmpNode.next.next;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        return removedNode;
    }

    public LinkedNode removeObject(int data) {
        LinkedNode removeNode = null;
        LinkedNode current = first;
        LinkedNode previous = null;

        while (current != null) {

            if (current.data == data) {
                removeNode = current;
                previous.next = current.next;

                break;

            }
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        return removeNode;

    }

    public int size() {
        int i = 0;

        LinkedNode tmp = first;
        while (tmp != null) {
            i++;
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public void display() {
        if (first == null) {
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            LinkedNode tmp = first;
            while (tmp != null) {
                System.out.println(tmp.data);
                tmp = tmp.next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
package com.custome.util;

public class LinkedNode {
    int data;
    LinkedNode next;

    public LinkedNode(int data, LinkedNode next) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: post code that other can run , here you have not shared code of your CustomeLinkedListImpl so no one can run your code

Answer (score 1):

A daemon thread in Java is one that doesn't prevent the JVM from exiting. Specifically the JVM will exit when only daemon threads remain. You create one by calling the setDaemon() method on Thread.
Daemon thread doesn't  wait for other thread to die.Waiting for other threads has nothing to do with daemon/user-thread.

The core difference between user threads and daemon threads is that the JVM will only shut down a program when all user threads have terminated. Daemon threads are terminated by the JVM when there are no longer any user threads running, including the main thread of execution.

Comment: post some some solid answer  based on op's code , as your answer is just definition of daemon thread , op is not about that

Answer (score 0):

> Differences between User and Daemon thread:
>
> - JVM doesn’t wait for any daemon thread to finish before exiting.

Here in your code your Daemon thread(producer) will alive till it will complete 20 iteration,

**Question : Producer thread dies and does not waits for the Consumer to die.**

**Answer : that is the actual behavior,  Daemon thread does't waits for the other threads to die**

Comment: Daemon thread in java is a service provider thread that provides services to the user thread. Its life depend on the mercy of user threads i.e. when all the user threads dies, JVM terminates this thread automatically.

I got above sentence javatpoint  http://www.javatpoint.com/daemon-thread

Comment: In multiple site and reference i read that "Daemon thread wait for user thread to die"

Comment: can you give site where its mentioned "Daemon thread wait for user thread to die" ?

Comment: I have already given the link of JavaTPoint in my above comment. please check it

Comment: already checked there but didn't get "Daemon thread wait for user thread to die" anywhere

Comment: As per my understanding:

Its life depend on the mercy of user threads i.e. when all the user threads dies, JVM terminates this thread automatically. is right? or could you explain this again, if i wrong

Comment: "Its life depend on the mercy of user threads" means if user thread will exit ,jvm will not wait for demon thread to terminate, it does not mean demon thread will wait for user thread, you can check behaviour of gc so you can get this clear